# Kafka Connect - File Source Connector error

Tags: java, apache-kafka, hortonworks-data-platform, apache-kafka-connect, confluent-platform

I am playing with **Conluent Platform/Kafka Connect** and similar things and I wanted to run few examples.

I followed quickstart from [here](http://docs.confluent.io/current/connect/quickstart.html). It means:

1. Install Confluent Platform (v3.2.1)
2. Run Zookeeper, Kafka Broker and Schema Register
3. Run example for reading file data (witk Kafka Connect)

I ran this command (number 3):

```
[root@sandbox confluent-3.2.1]# ./bin/connect-standalone ./etc/schema-registry/connect-avro-standalone.properties ./etc/kafka/connect-file-source.properties
```

but got this result:

```
SLF4J: Class path contains multiple SLF4J bindings.
SLF4J: Found binding in [jar:file:/root/confluent-3.2.1/etc/kafka-connect-opentsdb/target/scala-2.11/kafka-connect-opentsdb-assembly-0.0.1.jar!/org/slf4j/impl/StaticLoggerBinder.class]
SLF4J: Found binding in [jar:file:/root/confluent-3.2.1/share/java/kafka-serde-tools/slf4j-log4j12-1.7.6.jar!/org/slf4j/impl/StaticLoggerBinder.class]
SLF4J: Found binding in [jar:file:/root/confluent-3.2.1/share/java/kafka-connect-elasticsearch/slf4j-simple-1.7.5.jar!/org/slf4j/impl/StaticLoggerBinder.class]
SLF4J: Found binding in [jar:file:/root/confluent-3.2.1/share/java/kafka-connect-hdfs/slf4j-log4j12-1.7.5.jar!/org/slf4j/impl/StaticLoggerBinder.class]
SLF4J: Found binding in [jar:file:/root/confluent-3.2.1/share/java/kafka-connect-s3/slf4j-log4j12-1.7.5.jar!/org/slf4j/impl/StaticLoggerBinder.class]
SLF4J: Found binding in [jar:file:/root/confluent-3.2.1/share/java/kafka-connect-storage-common/slf4j-log4j12-1.7.5.jar!/org/slf4j/impl/StaticLoggerBinder.class]
SLF4J: Found binding in [jar:file:/root/confluent-3.2.1/share/java/kafka/slf4j-log4j12-1.7.21.jar!/org/slf4j/impl/StaticLoggerBinder.class]
SLF4J: See http://www.slf4j.org/codes.html#multiple_bindings for an explanation.
SLF4J: Actual binding is of type [ch.qos.logback.classic.util.ContextSelectorStaticBinder]
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoSuchFieldError: SYSTEM
    at org.apache.kafka.connect.cli.ConnectStandalone.main(ConnectStandalone.java:67)
```

In `ConnectStandalone.java` file on the line 67 is this: `Time time = Time.SYSTEM;`, but I do not know, why it should cause any error. Any ideas? Am I missing something important?

My working environment:

- Hortonworks Sandbox [HDP 2.5.0.0-1245]
- CentOS release 6.8
- Java: openjdk version "1.8.0_121"

Comment: It has something to do with [OpenTSDB connector](https://github.com/jeff-svds/kafka-connect-opentsdb). When I include JAR file in my classpath (according to instructions) I get the same output for both (as for File source connector as for OpenTSDB connector). When it's not set up I can run File source connector but not OpenTSDB one (connector is not found cause it's not in classpath). Not sure how to set it right..

Comment: FWIW, HDP already has `connect-standalone` script

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I meet the same problem on  ***"ConnectStandalone.java file on the line 67 is this: Time time = Time.SYSTEM"***

It is maybe that the  *OpenTSDB connector* depend on the version of  **kafka-clients-versionA.jar is different from the kafka-clients-versionB.jar under ./libs.**

Comment: It was exactly the problem, it's all about the versions. Finally I built this connector with different version defined in _build.sbt_ file and it helped! Thanks!