# How to resolve: ERROR Error while starting connector "java.lang.NoSuchFieldError: SYSTEM"

Tags: apache-kafka, azure-hdinsight, apache-kafka-connect

I am not able to get [kafka-connect-jdbc](https://github.com/confluentinc/kafka-connect-jdbc) 
working with `Kafka 0.10.1` on `HDInsight Cluster`. Here are the steps I went thru so far:

- I cloned the repo and ran `mvn install` and after struggling with the dependencies (not SNAPSHOTS), I got the jar.
- moved it to ./libs and I was able to see `io.confluent.connect.jdbc.JdbcSourceConnector` & `io.confluent.connect.jdbc.JdbcSinkConnector` when hitting `GET /connector-plugins`.
- I created a source connector to Azure SQLServer & a topic.
- I am getting the following error once, the source connector is created:

  [2018-02-14 15:46:16,960] ERROR Error while starting connector azure-source-connector-test (org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.WorkerConnector:108)
  java.lang.NoSuchFieldError: SYSTEM
  at io.confluent.connect.jdbc.source.JdbcSourceConnectorConfig.(JdbcSourceConnectorConfig.java:184)
  at io.confluent.connect.jdbc.JdbcSourceConnector.start(JdbcSourceConnector.java:69)
  at org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.WorkerConnector.doStart(WorkerConnector.java:100)
  at org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.WorkerConnector.start(WorkerConnector.java:125)
  at org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.WorkerConnector.transitionTo(WorkerConnector.java:182)
  at org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.Worker.startConnector(Worker.java:165)
  at org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.distributed.DistributedHerder.startConnector(DistributedHerder.java:773)
  at org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.distributed.DistributedHerder.startWork(DistributedHerder.java:747)
  at org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.distributed.DistributedHerder.handleRebalanceCompleted(DistributedHerder.java:708)
  at org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.distributed.DistributedHerder.tick(DistributedHerder.java:204)
  at org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.distributed.DistributedHerder.run(DistributedHerder.java:174)
  at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
- I tried different versions/branches of kafka-connect-jdbc but all trials end with the same error.

This [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43788122/kafka-connect-file-source-connector-error)
has same issue, so I tried to force the build to use `connect-api-0.10.1.2.6.2.3-1.jar` via `systemPath` in `pom.xml` but if the build goes thru, it still has the same issue.

Any idea?

Comment: 0.10.1 is pretty old. Have you tried this on a more recent version of Kafka Connect?

Comment: Nope, it looks like this is the latest version available on HDInsight :( - what is the most recent version?

Comment: Apache Kafka is currently at 1.0.0, with 1.1 around the corner. _0.10.1 is from October 2016_. Check out https://kafka.apache.org/downloads for how many releases there have been since. If you're tied to Azure, you could look at running Confluent Platform (which includes the latest version of Apache Kafka) directly per these links: https://www.confluent.io/landing-page/deploying-confluent-enterprise-microsoft-azure/ / https://azuremarketplace.microsoft.com/en-us/marketplace/apps/confluentinc.confluentplatform?tab=Overview

Comment: Thanks Robin, Finally, I got it working using kafka-connect-jdbc 3.0.2-SNAPSHOT. I will definitely take a look at your suggestions.

Comment: @MarkShehata Where can I find the 3.0.2 version of kafka-connect-jdbc?